# hour:min in laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

How can I convert minutes to formatted duration with hours and minutes?

I have an integer value in minutes I want to show it like:

```
// 1h20min
```

Instead of

```
// 80min
```

Comment: First, show us how you are showing it now, thatwill give us a number of clues about what and how you are doing things, all very useful when trying to help

Answer (score 0):

### Answer 1:

```
$minutes = 1510;
$hours = intdiv($minutes, 60).'h '. ($minutes % 60) . 'min';

This only works with php >= v7.xx !!!!
```

### Answer 2:

```
$minutes = 1510;
$hours = floor($minutes / 60).'h '.($minutes % 60). 'min';
```

### If you got a type error:

(because $minutes variable is a string)
you can cast it to integer like this:

```
 $minutes = (int) $minutes;
```

Comment: it works on any version of PHP  `floor($minutes / 60).'h '.($minutes % 60). 'min';` the `%` existed from before PHP 7